# Same function with and without template

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand a piece of code of C++11.
A class contains 2 functions as shown below:

```
class abc
{
public:
    void integerA(int x);

    template<typename typ>
    void integerA(typ x);
};
```

I am unable to understand benefit of declaring 2 same functions. Why not declare only one template function?

Only one benefit I can assume is we know `int` data type which can be passed to this function. This might be little faster. But for this, do we really need to create a separate function with `int` data type?

Comment: "I am unable to understand benefit of declaring 2 same functions": Because we might want to specialize `void integerA(int x)` to do something else.

Comment: @101010 You might want to try that as an answer.

Comment: Elaboration of what 101010 pointed out: If integerA is called with an int parameter, the non-templated function will be called. If integerA is called with e.g. a float or other type, e.g. a class of your own makng, the templated function will be called. This allows you to do something special for ints. The template specialization mechanism is an extension of the function overloading mechanism. It is quite powerful (and sometimes a bit complex, especially with multiple parameters),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason to do something like this is to specialize `void integerA(int x)` to do something else. That is, if the programmer provides as input argument an `int` to member function `abc::integerA` then because of the C++ rules instead of instantiating the template member function the compiler would pick `void integerA(int x)` because concrete functions are preferred when possible instead of instantiating a template version.

A more straightforward way to do this would be to specialize the template member function in the following manner:

```
class abc
{
public:
    template<typename typ>
    void integerA(typ x);
};

template<typename typ>
void abc::integerA(typ x) {
  ...
}

template<>
void abc::integerA(int x) {
  ...
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f0748f5d8ca839c)

Comment: As far I read the *overload*-approach of the OP is better than the *specialization* approach suggested here, see [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: @davidhigh I wouldn't argue on such matters, IMHO this is more a matter of taste. However, it seems that the interesting link you provided is broken "Not Found [CFN #0005]"

Comment: The link works for me -- at least now, I made an edit right after posting it. In it you find some arguments for overloading by a C++ authority ... just wanted to note that once.